# Output format of subprocess python

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm trying to keep the format generated by a command to see all wordpress plugin list.

my script is :

```
import subprocess
r = open("/tmp/resultplugin", "w")
f = open("path/to/my/list", "r")
for x in f:
        x = x.rstrip()
        bashCommand = "wp plugin list --allow-root"
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, cwd=x, shell=True, stdout=r)
        output, error = process.communicate()
```

The output of the command when launched directly on the bash shell :

```
| name                            | status   | update    | version    |
+---------------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| plugin name                     | inactive | none      | 5.2.2      |
| plugin name                     | active   | none      | 10.4.0     |
| plugin name                     | inactive | none      | 5.65       |
| plugin                          | inactive | none      | 9.4.8      |
```

The output when i redirect the output in a file :

```
name    status  update  version
plugin name    inactive        none    5.2.2
plugin name  active  none    10.4.0
plugin name  inactive        none    5.65
plugin name inactive        none    9.4.8
```

I have hard time to find how to keep the same format, or at least have a little bit more visibility as it's very hard to read in the file

Can someone explain me how i can format the output to the file correctly ?

Thank you

Comment: try something like this, to align the text into 'columns' https://stackoverflow.com/a/5085137/2670775

Comment: Even though "table" is the default format, try `--format=table` in your command (don't have high expectations for this)